# Symfony best practice for join tables ManyToMany

Tags: symfony, controller, many-to-many

I am relative new to Symfony (and PHP in general) and I was wondering how to accomplish the following:

I have 3 tables:

```
USER
  - id
  - lastNm
  - firstNm
  - username
  - isActive

COMPANY
  - id
  - name
  - isActive

COMPANY_USER
  - id
  - user
  - company
  - email
  - isActive
```

I want to create a rest api. 
Users can be created with a new company or can be added to an existing company. When a company is created, it's for a new or existing user. I need to add several properties to the COMPANY_USER table.

Which controllers do I need and what functions do I put in them? Especially for inserting, updating and deleting records.

The things I have in mind are too complicated, there must be a more elegant way to do this...

UPDATE:

UserController:

```
  /**
   * @Route("/user/add", name="user_add")
   * @Method("POST")
   */
  public function addAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, SerializerInterface $serializer)
  {
    $data = $request->getContent();
    $user = $serializer->deserialize($data, User::class, 'json');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword()));

    $em->persist($user);

    try {
      $em->flush();
    }
    catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
      return new Response(
        'Unique constraint',
        Response::HTTP_CONFLICT
      );
    }

    return new Response(
      $serializer->serialize(
        $user,
        'json'),
      Response::HTTP_CREATED
    );
  }
```

CompanyController:

```
  /**
   * @Route("/company/add", name="company_add")
   * @Method("POST")
   */
  public function addAction(Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer)
  {
    $data = $request->getContent();
    $company = $serializer->deserialize($data, Company::class, 'json');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($company);

    try {
      $em->flush();
    }
    catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
      return new Response(
        'Unique constraint',
        Response::HTTP_CONFLICT
      );
    }


    return new Response(
      $serializer->serialize(
        $company,
        'json'),
      Response::HTTP_CREATED
    );
  }
```

**How should the addAction of CompanyUserController look like?**

Comment: I would start with the [Database Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html).  Then be aware that you cannnot use Doctrine's builtin many to many relation because CompanyUser has additional properties.  You need to make a CompanyUser entity and establish one to many relations with your Company and User entities.

Comment: I indeed created the entity CompanyUser. But do I need a addAction in CompanyController, an addAction in UserController and an addAction in CompanyUserController. And in the last one, do I call the other addActions or do I duplicate my code? I'll add the addActions I have for now to this post.